# Programmatically change a shape's colour from a range

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, quartz-2d

How would I programmatically change the colour of a shape I have drawn based on a colour range?  My shape can have a value between 0 and 1 which defines its colour: full red (0)  to full green (1), with white as the mid range.  Please see the image link for the colour transition style.

http://combinationstudios.com/static/colour-range.png

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [gradients](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-SW14). [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-SW4) is Apple documentation on how to use them.

In your case, you will need to use three color components (red, white and green) and not only (red and green).

Comment: Thanks sch - that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are working with input (like 1.2 or so) You could link that input to the RGB value of your color range. With a formula I think you should achieve that.

Also in what are you programming?

grtz Robin

Comment: Objective C/Cocoatouch.  My question is more the mechanics of doing this - i.e. which bits of the framework do I need to look at and also the process to perform an RGB transformation and how I would setup my colour range?